# Change shared axis/hierarchy based on date slicer

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I am having some trouble dynamically altering my x-axis based on a custom date slicer.

Basically it works fine if the end-user is looking at every single date between 2020 and 2021, however, if the end-user filters to just a couple months, I want the column chart to skip the `Year` and just jump to the `MonthYear` axis to remove the user having to start from the year then drill down to see the months.

Similarly, if it was just days filtered in the slicer it should jump to the `Date` axis rather than drilling down from `Year` then to `MonthYear` then finally to `Date`.

How would I go about doing this?

Date Slicer:

[image]

Stacked Column Chart:

[image]

Shared Axis:

[image]

Comment: What you want to do is described in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hilfglpKNRQ

Comment: Thats exactly it! Thank you